# Arduino controlled by USB gamepad

Tags: usb, remote-control

I want to control my Arduino with USB gamepad. I know that exists library for USB keyboard for Arduino but I don't know any library for usb gamepad. I have PS3 styled gamepad. I dont want to use shield.

Any solution or help?

Comment: Does the controller act as a HID device?

Comment: Yes, Windows Device Managers says its HID-compliant game controller

Comment: If you've got a 32u4-based Arduino, I would start looking at the HID library, then.

Comment: and what model is your Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

A USB host shield or mini board depending on your Arduino board should work.

https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0

https://www.circuitsathome.com/usb-host-shield-hardware-manual/